# Displaying JavaFX Stage inside of swing application

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Like the question portrays, I need to display a [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) in a swing application.
As if I could cast it to a [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

For example:
`(JPanel)stage`

But of course, that's not possible. So, any ideas?

I appreciate it.

Comment: [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)?

Comment: You haven't done the least bit of research. A quick search on "JavaFX in Swing" would lead you to the answer right away ...

Comment: @StevenVanImpe I'm sorry but you're absolutely wrong. I was searching for a solution for over an hour and couldn't find a solution. Thankfully MadProgrammer found a solution, and it worked. So thank you MadProgrammer!

Comment: JediBurrell: type "JavaFX Swing" into Google. The top 3 links all link you to the tutorial MadProgrammer mentioned.